# virtual directory redirect in magento on linux

Tags: php, linux, apache, magento

Can anybody please help me, on iis I was able to create virtual directories which would redirect to certain pages eg yourstore.com/sale would direct to yourstore.com/t-salespage.php

how can I recreate this under linux for magento?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento offers URL-rewrite functionality out-of-the box. Simply login to your administration panel and use the Catalog -> URL Rewrite Management page to create a custom URL rewrite.